# Dask performs recomputation in branched graphs

Tags: python, dask, future, dask-distributed, dask-delayed

Suppose, I create the following graph:

```py
import dask
import time


@dask.delayed
def step_1():
    print("Running Step 1")
    time.sleep(1)
    return True

@dask.delayed
def step_2(prev_step):
    print("Running Step 2")
    time.sleep(1)
    return True

@dask.delayed
def step_3a(prev_step):
    print("Running Step 3a")
    time.sleep(1)
    return True

@dask.delayed
def step_3b(prev_step):
    print("Running Step 3b")
    time.sleep(1)
    return True
```

```py
stp_1 = step_1()
stp_2 = step_2(stp_1)
stp_3a = step_3a(stp_2)
stp_3b = step_3b(stp_2)
```

```py
from dask import visualize

visualize([stp_3a, stp_3b])
```

[image: branched computation graph]

```py
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster
cluster = LocalCluster(n_workers=1, threads_per_worker=3, dashboard_address="localhost:27998")
client = Client(cluster)
client
```

Now, I compute `step_3a` and it should take about 3 seconds.

```py
start = time.perf_counter()

stp_3a_futures = client.compute(stp_3a) # So that the future stays in memory

stp_3a_results = client.gather(stp_3a_futures)

duration = time.perf_counter() - start

print(duration)
```

```
[Out]: 3.1600782200694084
```

This makes sense. But now, when I execute `step_3b`, I expect it to finish in one second since it has already computed `step_1` and `step_2`. But, unfortunately, it doesn't keep those two steps in memory and the computation for `step_3b` also takes 3 seconds:

```py
start = time.perf_counter()

stp_3b_futures = client.compute(stp_3b) # So that the future stays in memory

stp_3b_results = client.gather(stp_3b_futures)

duration = time.perf_counter() - start

print(duration)
```

```
[Out]: 3.0438701044768095
```

Now, my question is:

- is there a way to keep `step_2` and `step_1` in cluster's memory using **ONLY** the delayed object of `step_3a` (i.e., `stp_3a`)?

I know I can call `client.persist()` on `stp_2` but that's not the answer I'm looking for. In my use-case, when I'll be computing `step_3a`, I won't have any reference to the delayed object for `step_2`.

thank you in advance for those of you who can answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `graphchain` works well with the recent dask version:

```py
from time import sleep

from dask import delayed
from dask.config import set as dask_set
from graphchain import optimize


@delayed
def step_1():
    print("Running Step 1")
    sleep(1)
    return True


@delayed
def step_2(prev_step):
    print("Running Step 2")
    sleep(1)
    return True


@delayed
def step_3a(prev_step):
    print("Running Step 3a")
    sleep(1)
    return True


@delayed
def step_3b(prev_step):
    print("Running Step 3b")
    sleep(1)
    return True


stp_1 = step_1()
stp_2 = step_2(stp_1)
stp_3a = step_3a(stp_2)
stp_3b = step_3b(stp_2)
```

Now, the computations:

```py
%time stp_3a.compute()
# Running Step 1
# Running Step 2
# Running Step 3a
# CPU times: user 330 ms, sys: 14.3 ms, total: 344 ms
# Wall time: 3.01 s

%time stp_3b.compute()
# Running Step 1
# Running Step 2
# Running Step 3b
# CPU times: user 6.4 ms, sys: 3.03 ms, total: 9.43 ms
# Wall time: 3.01 s

with dask_set(delayed_optimize=optimize):
    
    %time stp_3a.compute()
    # Running Step 1
    # Running Step 2
    # Running Step 3a
    # CPU times: user 364 ms, sys: 20.8 ms, total: 385 ms
    # Wall time: 3.04 s
    
    %time stp_3b.compute()
    # Running Step 3b
    # CPU times: user 5 ms, sys: 2.97 ms, total: 7.97 ms
    # Wall time: 1.01 s
```

Answer (score 1):

There is (was?) an attempt to do some graph-level caching/memoization, that you might find useful: https://github.com/radix-ai/graphchain

Aside from that, one can wrap all the desired results in one `compute` call:

```py
results = dask.compute([stp_3a, stp_3b])
```

This way `dask` will avoid recomputing the common requirements.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll take a look at graphchain (I'm afraid though that it might not be actively maintained right now).

Comment: w.r.t. calling `dask.compute([stp_3a, stp_3b])`, unfortunately, this doesn't help my case since I won't have access to `stp_3b` when I'll be computing `stp_3a`.