# Dask: Keep intermediate results on disk instead of memory

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I am building a data processing pipeline. The data is quite large: a data frame representing sensor data sampled at a high frequency. During the pipeline, I have an intermediate result which is a transformation of the data which is needed in subsequent transformations. Using Dask, I found that the intermediate transformation has to be re-computed in each subsequent transformation.

Is there a way to persist the intermediate result *on disk*? I am aware of `.persist()`, but this keeps the result on memory which is not an option due to the large size of my data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several solutions, in varying degrees of complexity, including:

1. most basic: include explicit persisting to disk. The rough idea here would be to create an additional function that checks if there is a persisted result, if there is one, the function loads and returns it, otherwise the function computes the result, persists it as a file, then returns it. The advantage of this approach is that no additional dependencies are introduced. Very rough pseudocode:

```py
def compute_and_persist(file_path):
    if file_path.isfile():
       obj = load_file(file_path)
       return obj
    else:
       obj = some_computation()
       save_object(object=obj, path=file_path)
       return obj
```

Such a function could be turned into a decorator, but as you can see it will require some coding. This is poor man's version of what `graphchain` does under the hood.

2. use third-party package, `graphchain`: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72521496/10693596) for a minimal example.
3. use third-party package, `prefect`: it has support to create persisted copied of the task results, see [docs](https://docs.prefect.io/core/concepts/persistence.html).

Comment: Thanks for the tips! Do you have a reference regarding point 1? By that do you mean using pickle manually etc.?

Comment: No problem, I updated the answer, and yes it could involve pickling or saving to another format, e.g. if this is a pandas df, then you could store the result in a parquet file.